# Japanese era information for specific date

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I'm developing a C# application (.NET Framework 4.5) and I'm unable to get the Japanese Era name and abbreviation for a date as specified in [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.japanesecalendar?view=netframework-4.5).
[image: Era information]
For example, for a date of 30/01/2010 I want to obtain the following information:
**name: 平成 (Heisei) -  abbreviation: 平 (H, h)**

I think that a possible solution is to get this information from Windows Registry but I would like to know if there is a solution based on .NET API only.

Comment: What do you mean by `Print`. Could you also specify how you intent on getting the name? How do you search for the era? It is very unclear what you are ultimately trying to achieve in your question.

Comment: I'm sorry if it's not very clear. I edited the question and remove the `Print` reference to avoid any misunderstanding. As my example show, for the date 30/01/2010 I would obtain the information about the associated Japanease Era, in particular the name "平成 (Heisei)" and the abbreviation "平 (H, h)".

Comment: It looks like the Eras are just integers and you need to consult the registry to get the names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DateTimeFormatInfo` class to get names for eras, specifically [`DateTimeFormatInfo.GetAbbreviatedEra`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.getabbreviatederaname?view=net-6.0) and [`DateTimeFormatInfo.GetEraName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.geteraname?view=net-6.0). Internally, it just fetches names from registry for you, so it's pretty much what was said in comments, but you don't need to do that yourself. Example for japanese eras:

```
        var calendar = new System.Globalization.JapaneseCalendar();
        var ciJapanese = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ja-JP") 
        {
            DateTimeFormat = { Calendar = calendar },
        };
        
        var dtfi = ciJapanese.DateTimeFormat;
        
        var date = DateTime.Parse("30/01/2010");
        var era = (calendar.GetEra(date));
        Console.WriteLine($"Era value: {era}. Era name: {dtfi.GetEraName(era)}. Abbreviated: {dtfi.GetAbbreviatedEraName(era)}");
```

Output:

> Era value: 4. Era name: 平成. Abbreviated: 平

There is a method in JapaneseCalendar class that allows one to get English era names ([internal static String[] EnglishEraNames()](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Globalization/JapaneseCalendar@cs/1305376/JapaneseCalendar@cs)), but it's internal and I wasn't able to find whether something accessible to us uses it. However, you could just copy that method and all the stuff it needs from the JapaneseCalendar class code and use it, or use reflection.

Comment: I marked this as accepted answer because it is a useful way to get the info in Japanese characters. However for the full informations (which include "Latin" characters version) I consult the windows registry in my own code.